# Hacked, possibly - has anyone seen this message before?

Tags: iphone, icloud

This afternoon, the touch screen of my phone became unresponsive. I tried to restart the phone but it would not. So I went on and deleted find my iphone profile because it stopped the phone from restarting. As soon that was done, my phone restarted itself. Then I saw the following message on my phone:

[image]

Has anyone had this problem before. What's the cause of it?

P.S. I have since reset my phone and changed my iCloud password just in case.

Comment: What do you mean "deleted find my iPhone profile"?

Comment: Log on to iCloud, choose 'Find My iPhone', then click on the device, click 'Erase iPhone'.

Comment: What happens when you call the number?

Comment: Why don't you find it out ;) ... I don't think it's a valid number - it's too short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the picture it looks like someone placed your device in [lost mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2700?locale=en_US). When a device is placed in lost mode you have the option to display a message and a phone number on the lock screen.

When you erased the device and signed back in with your Apple ID this would turn off lost mode for the device.

Comment: No one else has my iCloud access and that isn't my phone number. Does this happen often do you know by any chance?

Comment: I wouldn't have any idea how often it happens to people. When you place a device in lost mode you can have it display any phone number you want. Is your device jail broken? Installed any sketchy apps via third party stores?

Comment: Nope, not jail break + all legitimate apps downloaded from the official app store.